# Programming optional ignorance

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

In Javascript what is the best way to handle scenarios when you have a set of arrays to perform tasks on sets of data and sometimes you do not want to include all of the arrays but instead a combination.

My arrays are labeled in this small snippet L,C,H,V,B,A,S and to put things into perspective the code is around 2500 lines like this. (I have removed code notes from this post)

```
if(C[0].length>0){
    L=L[1].concat(+(MIN.apply(this,L[0])).toFixed(7));
    C=C[1].concat(C[0][0]);
    H=H[1].concat(+(MAX.apply(this,H[0])).toFixed(7));
    V=V[1].concat((V[0].reduce(function(a,b){return a+b}))/(V[0].length));
    B=B[1].concat((MAX.apply(this,B[0])-MIN.apply(this,B[0]))/2);
    A=A[1].concat((MAX.apply(this,A[0])-MIN.apply(this,A[0]))/2);
    D=D[1].concat((D[0].reduce(function(a,b){return a+b}))/(D[0].length));
    S=S[1].concat((S[0].reduce(function(a,b){return a+b}))/(S[0].length));
    }
```

It would seem counter-productive in this case to litter the code with tones of bool conditions asking on each loop or code section if an array was included in the task and even more silly to ask inside each loop iteration with say an inline condition as these would also slow down the processing and also make the code look like a maze or rabbit hole.

Is there a logical method / library to ignore instruction or skip if an option was set to false

All I have come up with so far is kind of pointless inline thing

```
var op=[0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0]; //options

var L=[],C=[],H=[],V=[],B=[],A=[],D=[],S=[];

op[0]&&[L[0]=1];
op[1]&&[C[0]=1,console.log('test, do more than one thing')];
op[2]&&[H[0]=1];
op[3]&&[V[0]=1];
op[4]&&[B[0]=1];
op[5]&&[A[0]=1];
op[6]&&[A[0]=1];
```

It works in that it sets only `C[0]` and `H[0]` to 1 as the options require, but it fails as it needs to ask seven questions per iteration of a loop as it may be done inside a loop. Rather than make seven versions of the the loop or code section, and rather than asking questions inside each loop is there another style / method?

I have also noticed that if I create an array then at some point make it equal to NaN rather than undefined or null the console does not complain

```
var L=[],C=[],H=[],V=[],B=[],A=[],D=[],S=[];

L=NaN;
L[0]=1;
//1
console.log(L); //NaN

L=undefined;
L[0]=1
//TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined

L=null
L[0]=1
//TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of null
```

Am I getting warmer? I would assume that if I performed some math on `L[0]` when `isNaN(L)===true` that the math is being done but not stored so the line isn't being ignored really..

Comment: NaN is a Number. Same thing happens if you set L to any other Number, L[0]=1; will behave the same

Comment: It's difficult to really get your intention. Your coding style is very exotic but not in a good way. More in a "it'll be hard read, debug and maintain in the long run"-way. Do you have a specific question or shall I just list a bunch of things you may want to check out?

Comment: The is a question of, How do I maintain a behavior based on an initial option with out having to go an constantly refer to the initial option.

Comment: Usually, breaking it apart in different functions is the way to go. But without knowing your actual usecase and actual code, it's hard to determine how exactly this would be done.

Comment: Don't forget you can also refer to the global object doing window['A'] or something like that for iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want I would do something like this.

```
var op = [...],
    opchoice = {
        //these can return nothing, no operation, or a new value.
        'true': function(val){ /*operation do if true*/ },
        'false': function(val){ /*operation do if false*/ },
        //add more operations here.
        //keys must be strings, or transformed into strings with operation method.
        operation: function(val){
            //make the boolean a string key.
            return this[''+(val == 'something')](val);
        }
    };

var endop = [];//need this to prevent infinite recursion(loop).
var val;
while(val = op.shift()){
    //a queue operation.
    endop.push(opchoice.operation(val));
}
```

I'm sure this is not exactly what you want, but it's close to fulfilling the want of not having a ton of conditions every where.

Your other option is on every line do this.

```
A = isNaN(A) ? A.concat(...) : A;
```

Personally I prefer the other method.

Comment: Thanks. Is it helpful? I had a little trouble understanding your requirements. I mostly considered the elimination of inline conditions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you repeat many of the operations. These operations should be functions so at least you do not redefine the same function over and over again (it is also an optimization to do so).

```
function get_min(x)
{
    return +(MIN.apply(this, a[0])).toFixed(7);
}

function get_max(x)
{
    return +(MAX.apply(this, a[0])).toFixed(7);
}

function get_average(x)
{
    return (x[0].reduce(function(a, b) {return a + b})) / (x[0].length);
}

function get_mean(x)
{
    return (MAX.apply(this, x[0]) - MIN.apply(this, x[0])) / 2;
}

if(C[0].length > 0)
{
    L = L[1].concat(get_min(L));
    C = C[1].concat(C[0][0]);
    H = H[1].concat(get_max(H));
    V = V[1].concat(get_average(V));
    B = B[1].concat(get_mean(B));
    A = A[1].concat(get_mean(A);
    D = D[1].concat(get_average(D));
    S = S[1].concat(get_average(S));
}
```

You could also define an object with prototype functions, but it is not clear whether it would be useful (outside of putting those functions in a namespace).

In regard to the idea/concept of having a test, what you've found is probably the best way in JavaScript.

```
op[0] && S = S[1].concat(get_average(S));
```

And if you want to apply multiple operators when `op[0]` is true, use parenthesis and commas:

```
op[3] && (V = V[1].concat(get_average(V)),
          B = B[1].concat(get_mean(B)),
          A = A[1].concat(get_mean(A));

op[0] && (D = D[1].concat(get_average(D)),
          S = S[1].concat(get_average(S)));
```

However, this is not any clearer, to a programmer, than an if() block as shown in your question. (Actually, many programmers may have to read it 2 or 3 times before getting it.)

Yet, there is another solution which is to use another function layer. In that last example, you would do something like this:

```
function VBA()
{
    V = V[1].concat(get_average(V));
    B = B[1].concat(get_mean(B));
    A = A[1].concat(get_mean(A));
}

function DS()
{
    D = D[1].concat(get_average(D));
    S = S[1].concat(get_average(S));
}

op = [DS,null,null,VBA,null,null,...];

for(key in op)
{
    // optional: if(op[key].hasOwnProperty(key)) ... -- verify that we defined that key
    if(op[key])
    {
        op[key](); // call function
    }
}
```

So in other words you have an array of functions and can use a `for()` loop to go through the various items and if defined, call the function.

All of that will very much depend on the number of combinations you have. You mentioned 2,500 lines of code, but the number of permutations may be such that writing it one way or the other will possibly not reduce the total number of lines, but it will make it easier to maintain because many lines are moved to much smaller code snippet making the overall program easier to understand.

P.S. To make it easier to read and debug later, I strongly suggest you put more spaces everywhere, as shown above. If you want to save space, use a compressor (minimizer), Google or Yahoo! both have one that do a really good job. No need to write your code pre-compressed.